# SQL Help - Delete records based on other records in order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

**Background/Setup:**

I am working with SQL Server 2008 R2; at the present point in my Stored Procedure I am working with a temporary table #benefits. My ultimate goal is to create a coverage map from a list of field changes.

The following sample table contains all the different scenarios for coverage changes that can occur (a worst case scenario). The table I am working with can be simulated like so:

```
declare @tmp table ([File_Name] nvarchar(3), File_Key int, Plan_Num nvarchar(4), Eff_Date datetime, Term_Date datetime)

insert into @tmp ([File_Name], File_Key, Plan_Num, Eff_Date) values ('IND', 1, 'A', '1/1/2014') -- Always delete this row, CLM is not yet A
insert into @tmp ([File_Name], File_Key, Plan_Num, Eff_Date) values ('CLM', 1, 'A', '2/1/2014')
insert into @tmp ([File_Name], File_Key, Plan_Num, Eff_Date) values ('IND', 1, 'D', '3/1/2014')
insert into @tmp ([File_Name], File_Key, Plan_Num, Eff_Date) values ('IND', 1, 'A', '4/1/2014')
insert into @tmp ([File_Name], File_Key, Plan_Num, Eff_Date) values ('CLM', 1, 'D', '5/1/2014')
insert into @tmp ([File_Name], File_Key, Plan_Num, Eff_Date) values ('IND', 1, 'D', '6/1/2014') -- Always delete this row, CLM is D
insert into @tmp ([File_Name], File_Key, Plan_Num, Eff_Date) values ('IND', 1, 'A', '7/1/2014') -- Always delete this row, CLM is D
insert into @tmp ([File_Name], File_Key, Plan_Num, Eff_Date) values ('CLM', 1, 'A', '8/1/2014')
insert into @tmp ([File_Name], File_Key, Plan_Num, Eff_Date) values ('CLM', 1, 'D', '9/1/2014') -- Key record (Remove for 2nd scenario)
insert into @tmp ([File_Name], File_Key, Plan_Num, Eff_Date) values ('IND', 1, 'D', '1/1/2015') -- If the key record exists delete this row, else keep
insert into @tmp ([File_Name], File_Key, Plan_Num, Eff_Date) values ('IND', 1, 'A', '2/1/2015') -- If the key record exists delete this row, else keep
insert into @tmp ([File_Name], File_Key, Plan_Num, Eff_Date) values ('IND', 1, 'D', '3/1/2015') -- If the key record exists delete this row, else keep
```

**Problem:**

It is possible in the system I am working with for a parent record to activate or terminate the coverage of a child record without actually modifying the child record. So I have to combine the field changes for both the parent record [IND] with the child records [CLM] to obtain a complete map.

**Help Needed:**

What I need help with is removing the [IND] records that I don't need. I only want to keep the [IND] changes that occur while the Code value for the last [CLM] change is A (Active). One of the sample records is marked Key Record, and based on it's existence the coverage map will change. Below are the desired coverage maps with and without the Key Record.

I need to remove: 
1) All IND records that occur between a CLM A and subsequent CLM D record and 
2) All IND records that appear after a CLM D record with no subsequent A record

After the undesired [IND] records have been removed I need to populate the Term_Date with the previous value's effective date. I have the code to do but it  requires the addition of an Identity(1,1) column and a self join update.

```
alter table #benefits add RowID int identity(1,1)
update a set a.term_date = b.eff_date from #benefits a, #benefits b where a.file_key = b.file_key and a.RowID = b.RowID - 1
```

I am pretty sure the same can be accomplished with a CTE, but I am not that familiar with them.

Thank you.

**Desired results with Key Record in place:**

```
CLM 1   A   2/1/2014    3/1/2014
IND 1   D   3/1/2014    4/1/2014
IND 1   A   4/1/2014    5/1/2014
CLM 1   D   5/1/2014    8/1/2014
CLM 1   A   8/1/2014    9/1/2014
CLM 1   D   9/1/2014    null
```

**Desired results without Key Record in place:**

```
CLM 1   A   2/1/2014    3/1/2014
IND 1   D   3/1/2014    4/1/2014
IND 1   A   4/1/2014    5/1/2014
CLM 1   D   5/1/2014    8/1/2014
CLM 1   A   8/1/2014    1/1/2015
IND 1   D   1/1/2015    2/1/2015
IND 1   A   2/1/2015    3/1/2015
IND 1   D   3/1/2015    NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution, it gives you gaps, I was going to ask if you want gaps  or not? if so it can be fixed another way.

The first part removes the IND what have a CLM with Plan_Num D.

```
delete a
from #benefits a
    left join #benefits b
    on a.rowid = b.rowid -1
where a.file_name = 'IND'
    and b.file_name = 'CLM'
    and b.Plan_num = 'D'

update a set a.term_date = b.eff_date 
        from #benefits a
        left join #benefits b 
        on a.rowid = b.rowid -1
```

Comment: I'm afraid that that query doesn't remove rows in either of the situations I am having trouble with. It in fact removes a record that I need to keep. I need to remove: 
1) All IND records that occur between a CLM A and subsequent CLM D record and
2) All IND records that appear after a CLM D record with no subsaquent A record.

Answer (score 0):

This should delete the records you don't want from @tmp

```
DELETE  t FROM @tmp t
WHERE   t.File_Name = 'IND' 
        AND ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 Plan_Num FROM @tmp WHERE File_Name = 'CLM' AND Eff_Date < t.Eff_Date ORDER BY Eff_Date DESC),'D') = 'D'
```